# How to get Liveview orientation using Sony Camera API

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, sony

I am currently trying to implement the Sony Camera API within a photo capture app.

I wondered if it is possible to detect the orientation of the Sony Camera (I am using the DSC QX10).  This means, I'd like to adjust the displayed Liveview on the screen of my iPhone depending on if the Sony camera is held in portait or landscape mode? (Currently I only achieved to implement the portrait view. In case I rotate the camera to landscape, the Liveview image on the iPhone is distorted.)

I hope my question is clear enough.

Best regards,
Josef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please download latest Camera Remote API SDK beta(v1.50 or later) and check out the "liveviewOrientation" parameter in getEvent response.

Best Regards, Prem, Member of Developer World team at Sony.